# Where are the Spree Mailer Settings entered in the Admin panel saved?

Tags: settings, spree, mailer

I am working on a Spree application using Rails 3.2.3. My version of Spree is 1.1.0. I am running my Rails server in development mode on my home computer. I have entered mail settings in the Spree admin panel at localhost:3000/admin/mail_methods. I can see the place in the development log where I entered the mail settings, and when I turn the server on and off, the settings persist, so I know that they are stored somewhere. However, I cannot find where they are stored. I set my SMTP Mail Host to be "smtp.hello.com", and when I do the following command from the project root directory, I only see the line in my development log where the mail settings were entered:  grep -r "smtp.hello.com" .

The reason I want to find these settings is because I want to find a way to set them without using the Admin Panel GUI. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in the sql database follow these steps

1st table is called spree_mail_methods note the id of the method that you want to set. 
but the actual data is stored in spree_preferences table the following sql statement will get you what you want as that table has a lot of data in it.

```
select * from spree_preferences where key like 'spree/mail_method%';
```

Shame on spree for storing passwords in plain text!

Comment: Thanks a lot, ashga. I was able to find it.